# Where to use Poisson point process/ Uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

When modeling the random locations of points in a one by one square, I am free to either model them by Poisson point process or Uniform distribution:

1) $N$ points are located in a one by one square according to a uniform distribution
2) points are located in a one by one square according to a Poisson point process with mean $N$

After modeling, I discuss the problem for large $N$, ($N \to \infty$). When should I choose Poisson and when should I choose uniform?

I know it depends on the problem I am considering, and I have to see to which of the distributions (Poisson vs Uniform) is the real problem is close to. But, if I know nothing about the real problem and have the freedom to choose either Poisson or Uniform, how should I choose?

Comment: Poisson is a discrete distribution, you can use it if you have only points in a countable set of places

Comment: @N74 Thanks. But, I meant Poisson process.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're modeling here. I'm also not sure how to interpret your usage of the term "Poisson process" when it seems like neither one of the axes of the square is understood as "time".

Comment: @Ian I meant Poisson point process. So, it is not time, it is modeling locations of points.

Comment: @Ian : You don't need time in order to talk about a Poisson process. Suppose you assign a random variable taking values in the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ to each measurable subset of the plane, in such a way that the random variable assigned to the union of disjoint subsets of the plane is just the sum of the ones assigned to those disjoint sets, and in such a way that the random variables assigned to disjoint sets are independent, and in such a way that the one assigned to each set is a Poisson-distributed random variable with expected value equal to the measure of that set. Then$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$that is a Poisson process. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Mathematically, sure, but the interpretation is less clear, and this question is all about interpretation.

Answer (score 4):

In your uniform distribution of $N$ points in a unit square:

- there will be exactly $N$ points in the entire square (so $0$ variance)
- in a subset of the square of area $A$, the number of points will be binomially distributed with parameters $N$ and $A$ (so mean $NA$ and variance $NA(1-A)$)
- in a second, mutually distinct, subset of the square with area $B$, the number of points will again be binomially distributed, this time with parameters $N$ and $B$; the number of points in the two areas will be negatively correlated

In your Poisson point process in a unit square with mean $N$:

- the number of points in the unit square will have a Poisson distribution with parameter $N$ (i.e. the mean and variance)
- in a subset of the square of area $A$, the number of points will will have a Poisson distribution with parameter $NA$
- in a second, mutually distinct, subset of the square with area $B$, the number of points will will have a Poisson distribution with parameter $NB$; the number of points in the two areas will be independent

You can choose whichever you think more suitable for your model.  If you choose the Poisson point process model and then observe the total number $n$, the conditional distributions in areas $A$ and $B$ given $n$ in total become the same as in the unconditional uniform distribution model with that value of $N=n$

Answer (score 0):

The content of the question has changed since this was posted,

It points are distributed in the square according to a Poisson process, then the **conditional** distribution of the locations of the sites, **given the number of sites**, is the same as if they were an i.i.d. sample from a uniform distribution in the square.

So that uniform distribution is appropriate when you are given the number of sites in the square. If the number of sites is uncertain, then you have a Poisson process.

Comment: Thank you very much. But, I meant uniform distribution of the number of points in a square.

Comment: @Su20200 : In that case I would need to know more about your problem in order to say anything.

Comment: Can you see my updated question statement? It looks like your area is EE. Let's think of positions of random wireless devices.

Comment: @Su20200 : Your updated question says it's NOT about uniform distribution of the number of points in the square, but rather about uniform distribution of the POSITIONS of a stated number of points in the square. So that means the answer I wrote above fits.